# Why scapy does not split the layers to fields

Tags: python, scapy, network-protocols

i created a new layer using scapy and i succeeded to send the new layer to another computer and show the new layer. My problen is when i send the layers all the data from all fields appear in the first fields and deleted from the another fields.

```
 import  sys
i, o, e = sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr
from scapy.all import *
sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = i, o, e
from scapy.packet import *
from scapy.fields import *
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP, IP
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether

class ID(Packet):
    name = "ID secret Traffic"
    fields_desc = [StrField("ID",""),StrField("LastName",""),StrField("FirstName",""),StrField("FatherName",""),
                   StrField("MomName",""),StrField("BdayLo",""),StrField("BdayHi",""),StrField("BirthLocation",""),
                   StrField("Gender",""),StrField("LocationOfIssuingID",""),StrField("Image","")]

bind_layers(UDP,ID,sport=217,dport=217)
bind_layers(ID,Raw,sport=217,dport=217)
bind_layers(UDP,Raw,sport=217,dport=217)
p = IP(dst='192.168.1.28')/UDP()/ID(ID='111111111',LastName="Kazo Cohen",FirstName="Omer",FatherName="Yaqqov",MomName="Irit",BdayLo="6121999",BdayHi="Kislev",BirthLocation="RamatGan",Gender="M",LocationOfIssuingID=" Tel Aviv",Image="fvvsgsgsfzfszvsfvfs")/Raw("KEEPALIVE")
p.show2()
send(p)
```

OUTPUT

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4L
  ihl       = 5L
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 120
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0L
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = 0xf6e9
  src       = 192.168.1.30
  dst       = 192.168.1.28
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
     sport     = 217
     dport     = 217
     len       = 100
     chksum    = 0xf332
###[ ID secret Traffic ]###
        ID        = '111111111Kazo CohenOmerYaqqovIrit6121999KislevRamatGanM Tel AvivfvvsgsgsfzfszvsfvfsKEEPALIVE'
        LastName  = ''
        FirstName = ''
        FatherName= ''
        MomName   = ''
        BdayLo    = ''
        BdayHi    = ''
        BirthLocation= ''
        Gender    = ''
        LocationOfIssuingID= ''
        Image     = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Your protocol is weird: how is the program (Scapy, or another program able to "talk" your protocol) supposed to guess that the `ID` field only contains "111111111", and that the rest is to be used for the next fields?

Usually, you have either a known "end-of-field" character (a null-byte can be an example), or a fixed length (it is known that the ID field is 9 characters long), or a field is used to get the length of the string.

Scapy can work with any of these options, using `StrNullField` or `StrStopField` for the first case, `StrFixedLenField` for the second, and `StrLenField` together with `FieldLenField` for the third.